# Finding shortest reverse path on a map, does such algorithm exist?

Tags: algorithm, dictionary, graph, path

I am looking for name (if such algorithm already exists) or help to build it as I have no idea where to start.

Firstly, take a look at two scenarios
[image: map]
<sub>(source: [ring0.cc](http://cap.ring0.cc/2d9b8cb8ce1666bd5283ae1df34b9e25.png))</sub>

What is what:

- Blue blocks are walkable blocks
- White blocks are non-walkable blocks
- All blocks are 1x1
- Green block is starting/destination point
- Red dots are waypoints(checkpoints)
- Numbers indicate order of visit
- Every block has its x, y coords
- Maps can have any shape

How does it work:

- A robot starts from green block and moves to waypoint `1`, next it visits `2`, `3` and so on until it reaches the starting point again
- Robot is able to find the shortest path on his own.
- I navigate itby showing him next waypoint location.
- Next waypoint cannot be further than 5 blocks (perhaps in this example I exceeded this value somewhere but assume it's no more than 5)
- The algorithm may assume that all waypoints are properly created (so there'll never be a situation that bot is in a position where nearest waypoint is more than 5 blocks ahead)

The problem:

Assume that bot right now is located in one of the positions indicated with red arrow. From this point he must discontinue his path and find shortest way back home. The problem is that I cannot give it X, Y coords of the green block because it's too far way. So if robot is right now at block `X`, it should move to waypoint `16` and continue normally, if it's at location `Y`, it should move to waypoint `17`(!!), from position Z it should move to WP `2` and then to `1` (which is actually backwards, unlike in scenario 1).

Limitations

- Every point holds only x, y coors, no other arguments may be stored
- Map file can only be read downwards, thus if I want to build a "back-path", I have to create a separate list which goes backwards
- The way I am defining path file is following:

  ```
  <!-- forward -->
  <WP name="3" />
  <point x=1 y=1 />
  <WP name="4" />
  <point x=1 y=4 />
  <WP name="5" />
  <point x=1 y=9 />
  <WP name="6" />
  <point x=4 y=9 />
  <WP name="7" />
  <point x=7 y=9 />

  <!-- cur pos 7 9 -->

  <!-- backward -->
  <WP name="8" />
  <point x=4 y=9 />
  <WP name="9" />
  <point x=1 y=9 />
  <WP name="10" />
  <point x=1 y=4 />
  <WP name="11 />
  <point x=1 y=1 />
  <WP name="7" />
  ```
- My available functions are: `getMyPosition()`, `goToWp(name)` - using this function I insert my "cursor" inside mapfile at the WP with name I passed as an argument, after that it continues as in mapfile, downwards.

The ultimate solution *could* be to write in mapfile every path possible but that would take ages for large maps :)

Things to note:

- Again, some paths are going backwards (like in scenario 2). Perhaps there is an algorithm which can find all points between my position and exit?
- There are 2 files: map file and script file. Map file is XML file with coords and waypoints, where script file is JS file where I can write whatever I want.
- Note that I can store all those waypoints in JS file too, for instance I could build a table of points with x,y coords if that could help
- Algorithm mustn't be efficient, it can even be `n!`
- Script cannot tell the robot to go to position x, y. It can only give him waypoint already defined in the map file.

That is a long question, I hope I explained it in a way so that you can understand the idea. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Take a look at the [A* path finding algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm).

Comment: Great job with the picture

Comment: Okay the picture is good, but I don't understand the question at all. It's obvious that you put a lot of effort in it, which is great. However it might just be little *too* much information. It would be helpful to reduce it to the necessary minimum. In particular, I don't understand the sentence "From this point he must discontinue his path and find shortest way back home. The problem is that I cannot give it X, Y coords of the green block because it's too far way." Why can you not provide the coordinates of the target and what is the robot supposed to do?

Comment: How large are the maps in terms of walkable blocks and number of waypoints?

Comment: Nicklas, I could give him WP of the destination but if the destination block is too far away from robot's current positon, it won't move. Robot is capable of finding path to a checkpoint only if the checkpoint is not more than 5 blocks away (means he cant make more than 5 steps to reach next checkpoint). Nuclearman, assume up to 20 checkpoints and map usually not more than 100x100

Comment: It sounds like the issue is that you are hardcoding the paths. Is it possible to use a Breadth First Search to find all shortest paths from the start/destination to each of the way-points. Likewise, if you just need to backtrack, is there anything preventing you from pushing the visited check points into a stack, then for backtracking just pop them back out of the stack to get which checkpoint to go to next.